# redirection to the admin interface without connection request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want the admin user to be redirected to the dashboard page without being asked to log in again.

```
<% if current_user.adminuser? %>    
  <li>
    <%= link_to admin_dashboard_path , target: "_blank", class: "btn-sign-out" do %>
      <i class="ace-icon fa fa-cog"></i>Admin
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the redirect in the `application_controller.rb`

So, it might look something like this:

```
# application_controller.rb

def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
  if _resource.adminuser?
    admin_dashboard_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

More information here: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Comment: is not it redirect for administrators?
For my case everyone has access to root_path.
but what I want to add is that when I redirect the administrator to the admin interface, we do not ask him to authenticate again

Comment: Well, it depends how you check if the user is an admin. If you check if the user is an admin with `current_user.adminuser?`, the example that I provided should work for you. Upon signing it, it is redirected to the *admin_dashboard_path*.